# Out of Memory Error Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Why are my getting Out of memory error for this cypher query

```
       MATCH sender-[r:COMMENTED]->errand  
       WHERE id (errand) = 214 
       RETURN sender, errand, r.ctime as ctime, 
             r.message as message, id(r) as id, 
             r.anonymous as anonymous 
       ORDER BY r.ctime ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 2000000000
```

**EDIT**I have less than 100 nodes in store.

Comment: How much memory are you configuring for neo4j and/or your JVM?  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-jvm.html#_configuring_heap_size_and_gc

Comment: which Neo4j version are you running? What OS?

Comment: Neo4j Enterprise on Windows 2.2.0-M02

Comment: it creates an array of size 2000000000 to sort into (top-k select), why would you use such an limit anyway? try limit 10 or 100 or no limit

Comment: Hmmn, perhaps it would better to create the an array the size of the nodes matching the query cause I have just 100 nodes anyway. That's indeed an expensive operation. I needed to be sure all nodes are returned for that query.

Comment: @F.O.O If you don't need to limit, don't limit :)

Comment: I would just do a return instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're returning potentially 2 billion rows. Try to lower the limit first. After that, it's up to what your machine can hold onto.

See comments:

> it creates an array of size 2000000000 to sort into (top-k select),
>   why would you use such an limit anyway? try limit 10 or 100 or no
>   limit
>   - [Michael Hunger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728812/michael-hunger)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this seems to be a problem in Neo4j 2.x.  We had queries in unit tests that happened to have an extremely high upper limit (just a technical accident; it only happened during test), and the tests passed in Neo1j 1.9 but started failing with Neo4j 2.x. 
"OutOfMemoryError: : Requested array size exceeds VM limit" 
etc.
Seems like in Neo4j 2.x the behavior changed to eagerly allocate the array the size of the LIMIT clause.
Easy fix was to set the LIMIT clause to be more reasonable.